# How do I add a file upload functionality in Slack app?

Tags: file-upload, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

So here is my use case. I have to create a Slack app in which the user should be able to enter some details and upload a file on the press of a button
The file will be saved on s3 bucket via a post request, however I do not know how to implement a file upload / file picker inside my slack app
Can anyone please tell me if there is any method in slack api for this?

Additional Info : I am using the Bolt framework for creating this app